# EXE gui for file launching

Tags: windows, gui

I am making a flash drive, that is used to play games, and run programs.

I was wondering if anyone has created a customizable GUI, to launch different apps and games, without having to look through the files and click on the right one. It would automatically launch when the drive is plugged in, and just be a easy menu for people to choose what the want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a local HTML file with links should work. It's quite easy to design that page as you want. As long as links are to files on the same volume as the HTML, it works.

But consider also creating shortcut icons on that drive, and customize the desktop appearance of the main folder of your disk: when you connect it, windows should propose you to open an explorer window to the volume, and will render the icons and your customized folder (all customizations are stored in the "hidden" desktop.ini file).

If this is for a collection of music files, consider creating an M3U playlist: just clicking on it will open your favorite media player.

No need of any application. If you need one, consider writing it in a scripting language which you can tune more easily: choose your scripting language, PHP, Python, CMD, node.js and use configuration files containing the easily modifiable lists (basic text files containing lists only with one item by line, or JSON if you need several fields, are much simpler than XML or CSV).

There are lot of tools that exist to create menus on DVD (not just playlists). They jsut require a small runtime or script engine you put on the DVD as well.
That runtime may be autolaunched, but consider placing a shortcut to this runtime at the root folder of your disk so you woin't have to search it when you insert the drive. all the rest can be organized in folders as you want, and referenced from your simple tunable datafile.

You can even find examples in various DVDs that you still find with some magazines (though not as frequently as in the 1990's and early 2000's because now everyone wants you to use their mobile app and advertize them with QR codes for Android or iOS, or an Hashtag on a social network where they have a page; but don't use these old apps made for too old versions of Windows), they all use a generic small app using now a scripting engine and it's simple to derive it if the app is not too much proprietary for the magazine.

Comment: How to I get it to link directly to the local file though, because HTML can't open files in anything but the web browser, and running a exe file wouldn't work in HTML

Comment: of course a web browser can launch a local file when you use the "local:" protocol (this is not blocked when the HTML is also local), and with "javascript:" URLs there are also ways to invoke local Explorer extensions (with the same restriction). Finally you can integrate a web browser component in an APP that will control itself the URL resolver and intercept clicks. But as I said, it's just simpler to use folder presentation styles: the file Explorer already has all what is needed (including scriptable desktop gadgets if needed)